# How to associate each node entry in DOM with an id?

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer

Using Google Chrome Puppeteer, I want to retrieve all user messages on a webchat-like page. I realized that when a user says anything within the same minute, like:

```
<div class="something"> 20:00 Hi! </div>
<div class="something"> 20:00 Hi! <div> <-- this one just a few seconds after
```

For me, the only thing that distinguishes this message from the other could be its xpath. But somehow as new messages arrives and the chat buffer scrolls, each message can get a new xpath value.

The question is: How can I distinguish each message if they have the same inner text and date/time?

Comment: maybe you could use the index of the DOM node ?

Comment: @keja Thanks for the idea. Indeed I just needed to grab the element index instead of the xpath. But then things got clear enough to figure out I needed to manually increment the index before I store it, because next time check it, it will be index + 1.

Answer (score 0):

As @keja pointed out, I just needed to get the index of the node element and save it somewhere.

The trick was: Because of something that appeared after the user message, the index had to be incremented manually before I store it somewhere. Like:

```
nodes.forEach((item, index) => {
  const { children } = item;
  const childrenArray = [...children];
  childrenArray.forEach((child) => {
    if (child.classList.contains(someSelector)) {
      const lineElement = [...child.querySelectorAll('div.someClass')];
      const element = lineElement[0];
      const text = element.innerText;
      lines.push({
        id: index + 1,
        text,
      });
    }
  });
});
```